# Как создать обычный Slider с помощью JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Этот код написал для кнопки <kbd>следующий (Next)</kbd> в обычном слайдере jQuery, но не знаю как делать кнопку <kbd>предыдущий(Previous)</kbd>. Но при этом надо сделать таким-же образом,как сделана кнопка <kbd>Next</kbd>. Вопрос:  Как сделать кнопку <kbd>Previous</kbd> таким же образом, как сделана кнопка <kbd>Next</kbd>?

```js
let index = 0;

$('#next').click(function() {
  index++;
  $('#ramka img')
    .eq(index)
    .css("left", "15%")
});
```

```css
#ramka img {
  height: 330px;
  width: 70%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#ramka {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#ramka img:not(#main) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ramka">
  <img id="main" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=slide1">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=slide2">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=slide3">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=slide4">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=slide5">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=slide6">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=slide7">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=slide8">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=slide9">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=slide10">
</div>
<div class="p-4">
  <button id="prev" class="btn btn-warning">Prev</button>
  <button id="next" class="btn btn-warning">Next</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: хорошо,спасибо))

Comment: `$('#prev').click(function(){    

  index--;

  $('#divforimg img')
                .eq(index-1)
                .css("left","-15%")

}` =)

Comment: нет,так неправильно,вначале я тоже так думал,но это не работает)))

Comment: Приведите в примере html код.

Comment: хорошо..приведено..))